# Where is the wiper relay located on a 1995 mercury grand marquis?

Tags: windshield-wipers, relay, mercury, grand-marquis

I need help repairing the wipers on my son's 1995 Mercury Grand Marquis. I have checked all fuses and replaced both the wiper motor and multi-function switch. Does anybody know where the wiper relay is located?

Answer (score 1):

**95 Grand Marquis Wiper Module Location**

[image: 95 Grand Marquis Wiper Module Location]